# VBA, Parse by "|" and Transpose, Next row

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following data in a cells A1

```
|stack|over|flow|
```

and cells A2..

```
|today|is|friday
```

How can I delimit this and transpose it into a vertical/column based view view?

Delimiting will give me data row based, which is good but that I have to transpose this manually each time. I plan to do this for many rows. I realized this could be tricky as the next row will need to be pushed back down for each time.

**Result A1:A6**:

```
Stack

Over

flow

today

is

friday
```

**Edit**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For unlimited rows and unlimited columns:

```
Sub splt()
Dim str As String
Dim col As Long, rw As Long, colcnt As Long, rwcnt As Long
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    colcnt = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'total no of columns
    For col = 1 To colcnt
        rwcnt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row 'total no of rows for specific column
        For rw = 1 To rwcnt
            str = str & .Cells(rw, col)
        Next rw

        rw = 1
        For Each Item In Split(str, "|") 'split string and display output
            If Item <> "" Then
                .Cells(rw, col) = Item
                rw = rw + 1
            End If
        Next
        str = ""
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
You can use an array for this, but the following method is less complicated to easy to write and read:

```
Sub splt()
Dim rw As Long, i As Long, rwcnt As Long
i = 1
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    rwcnt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'last non-empty row number
    For rw = 1 To rwcnt 'from row 1 till last non-empty row
        For Each Item In Split(.Cells(rw, 2), "|") 'split the string in column 2 from "|"
            If Item <> "" Then ' 'if the splitted part of the string is not empty
                .Cells(i, 4) = .Cells(rw, 1) 'populate column 4 with column 1
                .Cells(i, 5) = Item 'populate column 5 with splitted part of the string
                .Cells(i, 6) = .Cells(rw, 3) 'populate column 6 with column 3
                i = i + 1 ' increase i variable by one to be able to write the next empty row for the next loop
            End If
        Next 'loop to next splitted string
    Next rw 'loop to next row
    .Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.Delete 'when all data is extracted to Columns D-E-F, delete Columns A-B-C and your results will be in Column A-B-C now
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: worked nicely. Say if each row also had a header for each of these strings(so headers in Col A and the rows being delimited in col B). Is there a way to fill down these with their respective rows?

Comment: @Jonnyboi I am not sure I follow. It would be better if you could edit your question providing a screenshot of related cells.

Comment: does this clarify abit? like locking the cell with the delimited lines and filling down?

Comment: @Jonnyboi I hope this addresses your question. I suggest you to try to think how to solve your problem, even if you cannot solve it entirely for the time being. And do not copy paste these codes, try to understand what's going on in there. After a while, you will find yourself coding without any need for help. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, kind words.. You can be a lot better if you try.

Comment: do you have a blog? or website? did you just learn from this site?

Comment: At first most of my code was taken from the internet. I was changing small parts. After a while, one gets used to think the way it should be, and is able to create considerably bigger projects. And at the end, I found VBA do not meet my needs and interested in object oriented programming languages. This is probably what is going to happen to you if you keep working on this. I don't have a blog or website, just recently have decided to repay the days I have got help, by helping people myself instead, starting from this website.

Comment: so what did you switch to? Also can you explain the part of your code after `For`

Answer (score 0):

This one manages an unlimited number of rows on column A

```
Sub go()

    Dim strFoo As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastPosition As Long
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Set MySheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    MySheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert

    LastRow = MySheet.Cells(MySheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    LastPosition = 1

    For i = 1 To LastRow

        strFoo = MySheet.Range("B" & i)

        If strFoo <> "" Then

            arr = Split(strFoo, "|")

            For j = 0 To UBound(arr)
                If arr(j) <> "" Then
                    MySheet.Range("A" & LastPosition) = arr(j)
                    LastPosition = LastPosition + 1
                End If
            Next j

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Power Query` or `Get & Transform`

- Data --> Get & Transform Data --> From Table/Range

Then in the `Query Editor`

- Split Column by Delimiter

  - Use a Custom Delimiter:  the Pipe `|`
  - Split at left most (to get rid of that first pipe
- Remove Column 1 (the blank column)
- Split Column by delimiter

  - Use the Advanced Option and select to split into rows

Save and you are done.

Comment: Hi Ron, what is power query? is this a third party tool or microsoft add on to excel?

Comment: @Jonnyboi It has been part of MS Excel since 2010 or 2013.  In the earlier versions it is known as `Power Query`.  In 2016 it is known as `Get & Transform` and is on the `Data` ribbon.  If you have 2007 or earlier, it won't be present.

Comment: @Jonnyboi I am just seeing your data screenshot.  You will need some extra steps if you cannot make all the entries of Column 2 have the same format. The first line has a pipe at the end; your second line does not

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should have non pipe at the end of string, just at the beggining. so they should be same format in col B (or 2)

Comment: @Jonnyboi Well, if you have one of the later versions of Excel, it should be trivial to adapt what I wrote to what you really have.  And, you could also do it while recording a macro, if you must have a VBA solution.